# Recommended controller for multiple high-speed thermal sensors

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering

I am currently working on a project that will utilize 8-9 MLX90640 Thermal sensors which will all hopefully work at around 60Hz. This project is to measure the temperature of tires and brake rotors on a performance vehicle so the higher the refresh rate the more data for analysis. My problem comes down to how should I control these sensors, using which microcontroller/microprocessor or a combination of both.

I am currently using a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB, however, with the I2C bus set to 1 Mbit/s and only using 1 sensor with a Python Script, I am only able to reach a refresh rate of 8 FPs and this seems to be consistent amongst other people.

I am looking for a bit of guidance with selecting the right controller for my particular project, as well as just general knowledge on different controllers and their strengths/weaknesses.

If you need more information/clarification or want the Python code, I'd be happy to provide it.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Looking at specs, you're looking at 30 ish fps and not 60.  How you control depends on what you will do with the data.  Do you need continuous recording for processing later? Do you intend to process realtime?  Comes down to how much computing power and write speed you need.  With your current hardware, try for at least 3.4 Mbps

Comment: This seems to be a product searching question - budget, capability etc all things you get from reading the specs.

Comment: What is the present bottleneck? I2C?

Comment: 60Hz is not high performance., if processor is clocking at 700MHz.  Seems loike processor will do a lot of nothing.

Comment: Where did 60Hz come from?

Comment: @Able For the data, my goal will be to have it displayed in real-time on a small screen, and have the data stored in a file for potential analysis later on. In terms of write speed, do you mean the I2C Bus being set to 3.4 Mbps?

Comment: @Mattman944 Unfortunately I am not skilled enough to find the exact reason, I do know that the python script can only loop at most 7-8 times a second. I don't know if this is due to the I2C bus, the processor, or the python code itself. If there is any way to narrow this down I am all ears

Comment: @DKNguyen The 60hz is found on the MLX90640 Spec Sheet provided by sparkfun. It mentioned how the sensor can be programmed to have a refresh rate of either 2,4,8,16,32,64 Hz. Here is the link (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/7/b/f/2/d/MLX90640-Datasheet-Melexis.pdf)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat That's what I was thinking as well, how a powerful mini-computer like a raspberry pi 4 could not run through a few lines of code more than 8 times a second. This is where my knowledge runs short, I don't know what could be the limiting factor for the lack of performance.

Comment: Could the python code just be *really* inefficient? Did you write the code yourself? Maybe there's some error handling going on that is masking the fact that transmissions are only occassionally successful. Have you verified the signal integrity of the line? Scope the line to see if the signal is clean, and check to see if the length is reasonable for the speed and pull-ups being used. You can also add code to pulse an output at the beginning and end of a transaction, this could give you the time a transaction actually takes but error handling is all balled up into a single transaction.

Comment: I don't know python and it's pretty unreadable to put it unformatted into the comments. But I did see the "read it again if it fails" part and that sounds like something that masks failures. Get rid of it and do the output pulse test (or some other way to time how long a single successful transaction takes from beginning to end). Make it so transactions are only triggered manually and not just tossed out there until one works.

Comment: @DKNguyen The python code is quite simple actually, it starts by initializing variables, then a while loop which runs 1 line of code (mlx.getFrame(frame)) which is part of the adafruit_mlx90640 library, so my best guess if it were the code that was slow, it would be a problem within the library. I will change the wires leading from the sensor to the RPI to clear up any potential issues with that, and I will further tinker with the code and library to see if I can find any problems. (EDIT, Last comment was formatted wrong, I will do the recommended changes)

Comment: 'Asking us to find or recommend a product, service or other external resource' is disallowed by the guidelines in the Help Centre'.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend receiving the data with a fast microcontroller such as a Teensy 4.0. Get it working with one sensor and then just use 9 of them to read 9 sensors.

It will be easier to manage the i2c on a microcontroller so that you're fully utilizing the available bandwidth (and thus achieving the highest possible frame rate).

As others have mentioned, you should use an oscilloscope or logic analyzer like the salea logic 16 to ensure the i2c bus is being fully utilized (no long dead times between transmissions).

Answer (score 0):

From [MLX90640 32x24 IR array Datasheet](https://www.melexis.com/en/documents/documentation/datasheets/datasheet-mlx90640)

> The device use I2C protocol with support of FM+ mode (up to 1MHz clock frequency) and **can be only slave on the bus**.  The SDA and SCL ports are 5V tolerant and the sensor can be directly connected to a 5V I2C network.  The slave address is programmable and can have up to 127 different slave addresses.

> The array consists of 768 IR sensors.

[image]

Pixels appear to be 16 bits.  So just data (no framing), a 768 pixels sample is 12,288 bits.  At 60Hz, that would be 737,280 bits.  You then have to factor in framing (address, ack/nack, etc).  Which is why the sensor is a single slave off of a 1Mbit I2C master.

You have problems.  You want 8-9 MLX90640 Thermal sensors, which use 768 sensors (24 rows by 32 columns) and a I2C bus to communicate with a master.  You need 8-9 I2C separate I2C busses and the Raspberry Pi 4 4GB has one I2C bus.

You need multiple embedded controllers with multiple I2C ports or 8-9 Raspberry Pi 4 4GB.  Then something to process the volume of data.